# How to setup Angular8 CORS with ASP .NET Core 2.2 on localhost?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.2

I have read post about making CORS work on .Net Core 2.2 but still I could not make it work.

I have an Angular client running on localhost:4200 and a .Net Core 2.2 WebApi on localhost:5000.

The web api allow origin localhost:4200(client)

**WebApi Cors setup**

```
services.AddCors(options =>
        {
        options.AddPolicy(CorsPolicy,
            builder => builder
            .WithOrigins("localhost:4200")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

`app.UseCors(CorsPolicy);`

**Angular client header**

```
let headers_obj = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, content-type',
        Authorization:"Basic " + btoa(data.username+":"+data.password)
    }
```

Comment: You can use angular template of visual studio so everything can be run in same port. No need to add cors config

Answer (score 0):

you can use proxy to achieve that

first edit `angular.json`

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"<-----add this
          },
```

then create `proxy.conf.json` near the `angular.json` file
insert this

```
{
    "/Name_OF_API/1.0.0": {
       "target": "https://your_calling_api/",
       "changeOrigin": true,
       "secure": false,
       "logLevel": "debug"
     }
   }
```

then initialize your base path like this

```
protected basePath = './Name_OF_API/1.0.0';
```

then run and check `cmd` show your `proxy` setup

Comment: What is basePath? Is it the url string of api? Like this `api:string = "localhost:5000/api/";`? And also I couldn't get what is the NAME_OF_API I'm thinking if it is the .net core web api project name.

Comment: NAME_OF_API any name you like to call  and api is "localhost:5000/api/"